# Accord.NET to estimate Muliple Regression HMM model

Tags: c#, matlab, hidden-markov-models

The Accord.NET Project Home (http://code.google.com/p/accord/) contains examples of creating, training, and evaluating Hidden Markov Models based on sequences of one-variable observations.  I'd like to do the same, but with sequences of many variables.  I'm envisioning a multiple regression structure with a dependent variable and multiple independent variables.  I want to be able estimate an HMM where the output includes estimated intercepts and coefficients for each state, along with a transition probability matrix.  An example is time-varying betas for stock returns.  e.g. ret(IBM) = intercept + b1*ret(Index) + b2*ret(SectorETF) + error, but where intercept, b1, and b2 are state-dependent.

Marcelo Perlin offers exactly this functionality in his [MS_Regress package for Matlab](https://sites.google.com/site/marceloperlin/matlab-code/ms_regress---a-package-for-markov-regime-switching-models-in-matlab).  However, I want this functionality in C#.  So, any help would be greatly appreciated on either (1) using Accord.NET libraries to estimate a multiple regression HMM model, (2) translating Marcelo Perlin's package into C#, or (3) other ideas on how to achieve my goal.

Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

The Accord.NET Framework supports multidimensional features as well. You can specify any probability distribution to use in the states by using generics, and there is also an [example available in the documentation](http://accord.googlecode.com/svn/docs/html/T_Accord_Statistics_Models_Markov_Learning_BaumWelchLearning_1.htm).

If you have, for example, two-dimensional observation vectors, and choose to assume  multidimensional model assuming Gaussian emission densities, you could use:

```
// Assume a Normal distribution for two-dimensional samples.
var density = new MultivariateNormalDistribution(dimension: 2);

// Create a continuous hidden Markov Model with two states organized in a forward
// topology and an underlying multivariate Normal distribution as emission density.      
var model = new HiddenMarkovModel<MultivariateNormalDistribution>(new Forward(2), density);
```

and then you can learn the model using the generic versions of the usual Baum-Welch, Viterbi or Maximum Likelihood learners.

However, what the framework unfortunately still doesn't support is the exact regression form you mentioned. But it looks very interesting. Perhaps it could be added to the framework somewhere in the future. If you wish, please leave it as a suggestion together with some references and papers in the Issue Tracker of the project. It would seems like a very useful addition.